# Hosting Webpage over Local Area Network in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a C# form application that has different functionality. Additionally I want to add another service to the existing project which is hosting the webpage "`CameraCapture.html`" page over Local Area Network as a web service in order to be viewed from another client on the Network.

For this purpose I have added one form "`frm_cameraServer_monotor`" and two Buttons in this form, `btn_StartServer` and `btn_StopServer`, which to start serving "CameraCapture.html" and to stop serving it. My IP Address on LAN is: `10.140.191.200 (static)`.

I don't want to use any web server like Apache and ISS to be installed and configured. Just I want a server service to existing project.

Any one can understand and help me in this topic, really very appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if anybody can understand you. "I want to start web-service but without web-server".

Comment: Yeldar, yes you are.

Comment: But, i need to host my own page that I described in question detail.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267071/how-can-a-self-hosted-winform-wcf-service-interact-with-the-main-form

Comment: I checked it. But not complicated like that, just I want simply bind it with my IP address and use from other client.

Comment: do you need to provide "CameraCapture.html" OR webService? html is static content.. If you want to provide webService accessible as "CameraCapture.html" then you are intentionally confusing the consumer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to start web-service but without web-server

If it is just a plain HTML without back-end but not a web-service, then you can create a shared folder and open it as a file from your network. HTML and front-end JS scripts will work well. However, the link will be like:

```
file:\\COMPUTER-001\Camera\CameraCapture.html
```

If it is ok for you, then you can easily do this without web-server.

You surely cannot make it work this way without any HTTP-server:

http://COMPUTER-001/CameraCapture.html

Is it worth it?
Install a simple web-server, you even won't need to configure it if a single HTML file is everything you need.

Comment: Ok, good, so can I run this http://COMPUTER-001/CameraCapture.html as a service from my application?

Comment: @NurSelam What do you mean "as a service"? How do you see a difference? You mean "HTTP service" which is browsable at `http://`? No, you can't. Unless you install a web-server like Apache, IIS etc.

Comment: without sharing it, how other clients can access it?

Comment: @NurSelam If you don't run a web-server and don't share a folder, other clients cannot access this file.

Comment: I know that, but programatically how can I share "CameraCapture.html" file from my Application, to be accessible, if no need web server?

Comment: Be cause I don't want to go on the Computer shared folder to do that, just I want to share it from my Application.

Comment: I accept your answer, now I know it is static page. Thanks.

Comment: though you have accepted the answer, but still have a look at light-weight web server mongoose http://cesanta.com/mongoose.shtml.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to host an asp.net site on your application (winforms/service/wpf/whatever) you can use [CassiniDev](https://cassinidev.codeplex.com/)

Then simply publish your web project to your filesystem and use:

```
        CassiniDev.Server server = new CassiniDev.Server({port number}, {publishedSitePath});
        server.Start();
```

Comment: I want to host html page, not asp.net. Just publish it and use over LAN

Comment: Then you can use @Yeldar 's solution, html pages can be opened directly from most (if not all) of the browsers. simply provide the direct path in the address bar