# Hosted WCF Service Calling WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a C# WinForms app which is hosting a WCF service. When I call this service from another app, I want that method in the WCF service to call a method on the Form. I could cast the Form.ActiveForm but this doesn't seem a good way to do it. What would be the best way to call the Form from the hosted WCF service?

Comment: How do you create WCF host and main form? There, with a property, may be appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution elsewhere on StackOverflow. I had previously searched on here before posting my question but missed this one

[How can a self-hosted (WinForm ) WCF service interact with the main form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267071/how-can-a-self-hosted-winform-wcf-service-interact-with-the-main-form)

This works nicely so thought I'd update here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use events. The form registers to the event while the service triggers the event

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this as I'm relatively new to C#

Comment: This article on codeproject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable show how to create a simple custom event. The "Listener" class would be you form, the "Metronome" class would be your WCF service

Comment: I see how I can do this for the form but I don't see how it would work for the WCF service. I create the service with NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(); host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), baseAddress); host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding, baseAddress);host.Open(); So at that point I don't see how I can tell the form to subscribe to it. Surely WCF will create MyService as and when calls come into it and this could be on a PerCall basis if I decide to go that route.