# Communication between WPF and hosted WCF Service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a console app that starts a WCF service and a small WPF app. I'm trying to show a messagebox in the WPF app whenever a method on the WCF service is called for testing purposes.
I have based my code on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267071/how-can-a-self-hosted-winform-wcf-service-interact-with-the-main-form) answer but the synchronizationContext is null. How do i fix this?
Or are there other/better ways to make this happen?

Comment: [Walkthrough: Creating a WCF Data Service with WPF and Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/walkthrough-creating-a-wcf-data-service-with-wpf-and-entity-framework?view=vs-2017), however in your case you dont need the synchronizationContext jsut comment the line out

Comment: Did you make sure your synchronizationcontext is a field set by the GUI? As shown in the example you used; set the field synchronisationcontext in the constructor of the Form. Then use that field in the service methods. 
These service methods probally do not run on the GUI thread, so they have no synchronizationcontext (thats why they have to synchronize to he GUI context).

Answer (score 0):

Use [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr). Lots of info [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/monitor-inside-your-running-services-using-signalr-and-wcf/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24185477/1177147). [This article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Sep/04/SelfHosting-SignalR-in-a-Windows-Service) also looks very good.

As for actual code, create a WCF service and use NuGet to add a reference to SignalR, then add a hub class:

```
public class ServiceMonitorHub : Hub
{
}
```

You'll also need to add an Owin startup class to start the SignalR hub:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourNamespace.SignalRStartup))]
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class SignalRStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Your service handlers can then get a reference to this hub and send messages to all the clients that are connected to it:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        // send msg to clients
        var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ServiceMonitorHub>();
        hub.Clients.All.BroadcastMessage();

        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
```

Your WPF client then connects to this SignalR server and hooks in handlers to receive the messages send by the service handlers, this example contains a button handler that calls the service, as well as a connection to the SignalR hub to receive the messages that bounce back:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private HubConnection Connection;
    private IHubProxy HubProxy;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Task.Run(ConnectAsync);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var service = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
            service.GetData(1);
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:59082/");
            this.HubProxy = this.Connection.CreateHubProxy("ServiceMonitorHub");
            HubProxy.On("BroadcastMessage", () => MessageBox.Show("Received message!"));
            await this.Connection.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

}

Note that clients need the NuGet SignalR.Clients package (as opposed to just SignalR).

There are other ways for services to call the hub clients, [this link](https://dotnetsilverlightprism.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/signalr-wcf-solid-ways-an-soa-wcf-notification-service-can-use-signalr/) shows a few others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try ClientMessageInspector, the AfterReceiveReply of it will be called every time the client receives the message.

```
 public class MyClientMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
          Your message box
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
       show message in your message box
    }
    public MyClientMessageInspector ( ){

                       }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

To register the Inspector , you need to use an endpointBehavior

```
  public class MyEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add( new MyClientMessageInspector();
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {

    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {

    }
}
```

And then add the behavior to your client.

```
 using (ChannelFactory<IService> ChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>("myservice"))
        {
            ChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new MyEndpointBehavior());
            IService service = ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
          // call method


        }
```